# Xamarin - Android SDK 26

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I downloaded and opened Xamarin when I run my app it says I need to install Android SDK 26, I'm currently debugging app on my Galaxy Note 4 Android 6.0.1, I have no problem on Android Studio and I also haven't added any code to the project, just clicked on the "run" button.

Comment: Have you set JDK and Android SDK path  in Xamarin(Visual Studio)

Comment: I want to know what is your develoment environment? You developed in android studio, did you want to run it in Visual studio? Or you could share your demo.

Comment: @LeonLu-MSFT No, When I do the same thing in Android Studio it goes well, but when I do it in Xamarin Studio,  It gives me an error which I mentioned above.

Comment: Could you share a demo? Only through your description, I am not sure where the problem is.